# Get-Command -syntax returns just the first set of parameters when using dynamic parameters

Tags: powershell

I am having a hard time understanding how Powershell resolves syntax when using dynamic parameters.

A simple, reproducible example:

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace SOQuestion
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Greeting")]
    public class GetGreeting : PSCmdlet, IDynamicParameters
    {
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true)]
        public NameType NameType { get; set; }

        private object context;
        public object GetDynamicParameters()
        {
            switch (NameType)
            {
                case NameType.First:
                    context =  new DynParamsFirst();
                    return context;
                case NameType.Full:
                    context = new DynParamsFull();
                    return context;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid type specified");
            }
        }
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            string name;
            switch (NameType)
            {
                case NameType.First:
                    DynParamsFirst first = context as DynParamsFirst;
                    name = first.FirstName;
                    break;
                case NameType.Full:
                    DynParamsFull full = context as DynParamsFull;
                    name = full.First + " " + full.Last;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid type specified");
            }
            WriteObject($"Hello {name}!");
        }
    }

    public enum NameType
    {
        First = 0,
        Full = 1
    }

    public class DynParamsFirst
    {
        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = true)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }

    public class DynParamsFull
    {
        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = true)]
        public string First { get; set; }
        [Parameter(Position = 2, Mandatory = true)]
        public string Last { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This runs as expected when supplying the parameters in the CLI, my parameters are nicely dynamic, and I get the expected output.

But when I run `Get-Command Get-Greeting -syntax` I get:

`Get-Greeting [-NameType] <NameType> [-FirstName] <string> [<CommonParameters>]`

Those are the parameters that belong to `DynParamsFirst`. There is no indication of parameters being dynamic. I found that the syntax being pulled is the syntax for the first match in the `NameType` enum - if I set `Full` to `0` in the `NameType` enum, then `Get-Command Get-Greeting -syntax` will output the parameters for `DynParamsFull` instead. Also, most likely related, if I enter `Get-Greeting` without parameters and hit Enter, I always get just `FirstName`, which throws an error in combination with the `Full` NameType.

I find that surprising and it is giving a hard time documenting the command. I also find it non-trivial to formulate a proper question.

Here goes: How do I change the code so that when entering the command without parameters, Powershell is aware that there are dynamic parameters involved?

Comment: Have a look at what the [`Trace-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/trace-command?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet shows you. `Example 2: Trace the actions of ParameterBinding operations`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-NameType` is your cmdlet's only *static* parameter. Its default value is implicitly `[NameType]::new()`, i.e., the `[NameType]` type's implicit default value: as an `enum`-derived type, i.e. as a .NET *value type*, it *implicitly* has a default constructor that initializes the value to all zeros, which in your case translates to `NameType.First`:

Therefore, without (implied) additional context, `Get-Command Get-Greeting -Syntax` behaves as if you had passed `-NameType First` to `Get-Greeting`, and that's the syntax diagram you see: it shows the corresponding `-FirstName` dynamic parameter:

```sh
PS> Get-Command Get-Greeting -syntax # implies: -Args '-NameType', First - see below.

Get-Greeting [-NameType] <NameType> [-FirstName] <string> [<CommonParameters>]
```

In order to see what other syntax diagrams may apply *situationally*, you have to pass *pass-through* arguments to `Get-Command -Syntax` via its `-ArgumentList` / `-Args` parameter, which then shows the *situationally appropriate* syntax, _as if those arguments were passed to the target command, `Get-Greeting`:

```sh
PS> Get-Command Get-Greeting -syntax -Args '-NameType', Full

Get-Greeting [-NameType] <NameType> [-First] <string> [-Last] <string> [<CommonParameters>]
```

Note the perhaps surprising need to *quote* `-NameType`, lest it be interpreted as another parameter *name* rather than as a parameter *value* passed to `-Args` - see [GitHub issue #4624](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4624).

Comment: Excellent explanation and a useful note I wasn't aware of on how to see other dynamic parameter sets. Something to point out - if you wanted to show no dynamic parameters unless a value is specifically defined, before checking the value of NameType check if `MyInvocation.BoundParameters.ContainsKey(nameof(NameType))` - that'll tell you if the user has specified a `NameType` instead of the value just being `default(NameType)`, without using `Nullable<T>` (therefore being more clear to the end-user).

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. From a point of discoverability, would you say the above implemenation is poor design?

Comment: @Rno, discoverability is tricky, for sure. The typical use case is for dynamic parameters to depend on the provider context, where the current location (`$PWD`) _implicitly_ provides the context and surfaces the dynamic parameters automatically. That's why `Get-ChildItem -?` shows the dynamic `-Directory` parameter - added by the `FileSystem` provider, when the current location is a file-system location (which is typical).

Comment: @Rno, perhaps the better approach in your case is to use static parameters only and simply make `-Last` _optional_. Generally speaking,  [parameter sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parameter_Sets) can help you implement different sets of (static) parameter combinations, so you could do `Get-Greeting -FirstName <string>` as one set, and `Get-Greeting -First <string> -Last <string>` as another.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the suggestion. I arrived at this approach because I could not get it working using parameter sets (the actual cmdlet is more complex than above code). I forgot why that was, I believe it had to do with multiple mandatory paramers not being manadatory anymore, buit would have to revisit it.

Comment: @mklement0 the problem with the parameter set approach is that as I understand it, please correct me if I am wrong, the 'flow' of a cmdlet changes when providing a different parameter, whereas what I want is to change the flow when ta parameter *value* changes (ergo, the above example).

Comment: @Rno, yes, it is different parameter _names_ that select different parameter sets, not _values_.  But at least in your example you don't strictly need a `-NameType` parameter, you could use `Get-Greeting -FirstOnly` vs. `Get-Greeting -First -Last`, or simply make do with a single set comprising both `-First` and `-Last`, making the latter optional. If you truly need to offer additional parameters based on a given static parameter's situational value, dynamic parameters are your only option (unless you want to perform manual validation in the function body, which is suboptimal).

Comment: @Rno, and if you do use dynamic parameters this way, you'll invariably have a discovery problem - you could mitigate that by mentioning the dynamic parameters in the _description_ part of the cmdlet's help.

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you for you input, it has been very enlightning. FWIW I managed to mimic the dynamic approach with parameter sets by creating switch parameters for every enum value. That technically works but it  makes for an even more confusing UX than 'undiscoverable' syntax, even though the -Syntax parameter outputs it all nicely. It also still has another problem: I cannot use `IArgumentCompleter` to its full potential. But I digress now. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Rno; my pleasure. Consider asking a new question for the tab-completion problem.